# Как получить содержимое по отдельности из div блоков с одним классом?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Необходимо получить содержимое по отдельности из div блоков с одним классом (другие классы и id не добавлять в блоки).

Есть такой код:

```js
var onediv = $(".divid").html();
var twodiv = $(".divid").html();

console.log("первый блок: " + onediv + "\n Второй блок: " + twodiv);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='divid'>Info 1 block</div>
<div class='divid'>Info 2 block</div>
```

Думал можно сделать что-то типа `$(".divid")[1].html();` и `$(".divid")[2].html();`, но не получилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var onediv = $(".divid:eq(0)").html();
var twodiv = $(".divid:eq(1)").html();

alert("Первый блок: "+ onediv +"\n Второй блок: "+ twodiv);

$('.divid').each(function() {
  // alert($(this).text());
  alert($(this).html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="divid">Info 1 block</div>
<div class="divid">Info 2 block</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо) не знал об этой функции к сожалению.

Comment: Можно собрать данные с блоков с одинаковыми классами разными способами, указав конкретный порядковый номер, либо перебрать элементы через `each`

Comment: @ChipaChop не забудьте отметить ответ, если задача решена.

Comment: пока что не могу ни чего отметить. 5 минут пишет...